# PDF file demands latest Acrobat, how can I read it?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader, adobe-acrobat

I downloaded my college transcript and the file demands the latest version of Adobe Acrobat. After poking around I downloaded Adobe Reader 9.5.5 but the PDF won't cooperate since that program's too old.

Is there a workaround, or are there PDF readers for Linux capable of spoofing the latest Acrobat? I don't have a Windows computer.

Comment: Evince is the file reader that supports PDFs and comes with Ubuntu by default. Tried that ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on experience Foxit Reader is the best and most updated PDF reader for Ubuntu. You can get it here:
[Foxit PDF Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/pdf-reader/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use latest version of "Adobe Acrobat Reader DC" along with wine although Adobe discontinued their PDF reader software for Linux several years ago. It works perfect for me.

First install `wine` and `winetricks`

```
sudo apt install wine-stable winetricks
```

Prepare wine to receive Acrobat Reader DC installation:

```
winetricks mspatcha
```

Download the latest version of Adobe Reader for Windows 10 from official site http://get.adobe.com/uk/reader/otherversions/

A file with extension exe will be downloaded. (`AcroRdrDC1801120040_en_US.exe`)
Now install that exe file in wine:

```
wine AcroRdrDC1801120040_en_US.exe
```

(Use the same name as that of downloaded exe file)

Click `Install` button.

Wait until the setup is completed and click on `Finish`.

Now search for Acrobat Reader in applications menu and open it.

Select `Always open with Protected Mode Disabled`. (Adobe Reader DC runs in protected mode by default to provide an added layer of security)

Accept Licence.

Now you can open your files using Acrobat Reader DC even on Ubuntu.